# Difference between search online and online search

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between *search online* or *online search* or is only one of them correct?

Example sentence

> He's been doing a search online for a while.

Comment: There aren't many contexts where *He's been **doing a search online** for a while* wouldn't be better expressed as *He's been **searching online** for a while.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/online) shows that **online** can be an *adjective* or an *adverb*.

> **adjective** example: *online banking/shopping*
> He's been doing an online search for a while.

> **adverb** example:  *Do you like to shop online?*
> He's been doing a search online for a while.

Answer (score 1):

There are subtle differences in emphasis, when someone uses these expressions :

1. "Search online" emphasizes the action of searching and specifies that the search is being conducted on the internet.
2. "Online search"/“web search” emphasizes the location or medium of the search, indicating that it's being done via the internet. “Offline search” could mean searching from the books, articles, newspapers and other sources that do not involve the internet.

"Search on the internet" or “search on the web” is similar to "search online" but explicitly mentions the internet as the platform for searching.

Answer (score -1):

"Search online" is a verb phrase. "Online search" is a noun phrase.

"I searched online for information about aardvarks."

"I did an online search for information about aardvarks."

"He's been doing a search online ..." is valid but not something fluent English speakers often say. Most would say, "He as been searching online ..." or "He has been doing an online search ..."